# How I open a day from month view in Outlook Calendar?

Tags: microsoft-outlook

When I display the month view in Outlook Calendar I can see my events and appointments for that month. However, how can I from this month view open a specific day lets say the 25 of June? I tried to double click but it didn't open the day view for that specific day instead it opens a new appointment windows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Click on the day you want just once so that you can see that day has been highlighted.

Click on the View Tab in the ribbon and then in View click on Day and the day you had highlighted opens.

Very straightforward.  Here is a screen shot to assist.

[image]

Comment: Good sharing! This suggestion is really useful!